# how to start windows service on particular time

Tags: c#, windows-services

i want to start my windows service on every sunday 1.00 A.M.

can anyone help me in this

Comment: You could use the Task Scheduler for that purpose. All you have to do is find a way of adding tasks through C# :)

Comment: Services are always start at windows startup. You will need, as @Oscar said, Task Scheduler to start your app at a specific time and date.

Answer (score 4):

If it has to run on every sunday 1.00 AM then probably you need a simple program that is run by task scheduler on 1 AM Sunday.

It would be better if you use a timer that fires say every one hour and check what day and time it is. If it is sunday and 1 AM you can disable the timer and carry on with the work you want to do in the service. After the work is done then you should re-enable the timer.

Answer (score 2):

One way could be to use SC command in a batch file which can be scheduled to run from windows standard scheduler.

For more information, see

```
SC /?
```

start and stop parameters in particular.

Answer (score 0):

Since the logic should be done once in a week at a particular time use windows task scheduler for your purpose.

If you do not know how to perform this, Create a **sample.vbs** file, which calls your asp.net page/web service where you perform the logic. Then create a schedule in windows task scheduler to trigger your sample.vbs file.

Please see the steps to **create the .vbs file** that calls your asp.net page/web service

1.Open notepad and copy the following code in it and save

```
   'Declare variables
      Dim objRequest
      Dim URL

    Set objRequest = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

   'Put together the URL link appending the Variables.
      URL = "http://computerName/VirtualDirectoryName/Logic.aspx"

  'Open the HTTP request and pass the URL to the objRequest object
      objRequest.open "POST", URL , false

  'Send the HTML Request
      objRequest.Send

  'Set the object to nothing
      Set objRequest = Nothing
```

2.Edit the URL="with your virtual directory path to the asp.net page/web service" and save.

3.change the extension from ".txt" to ".vbs" and save.

4.Create a new schedule in windows "Task Scheduler" and point the newly created sample.vbs file which will call the page where your logic is written (http://computerName/VirtualDirectoryName/Logic.aspx) and edit the settings to run once in a week at a particular time.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is like this:

1. First you install your windows service on your Windows Server.
2. Second, you make a batch file. You just open Notepad, write the line beneath and save it as a .bat.

   > net start myService
3. Then you use the Task Scheduler available in Windows Server.

Creating the task is easy, you just need to add a trigger event (every sunday) and an action (starting the batch file you've just created).

I'm not saying it is the best way, but it is a way that will work.